# Run django-admin.py , raise error "Could not import settings 'mysite.settings' "

Tags: python, django

Win 7 + python 2.7 + django 1.5.8

I don't know what I have done with my PC but yesterday `django-admin.py startproject` was working. How do I fix it? Thanks for your time.

```
c:\Python27\Scripts>django-admin.py
      Usage: django-admin.py subcommand [options] [args]

Options 
      -v VERBOSITY, --verbosity=VERBOSITY
                    Verbosity level; 0=minimal output, 1=normal output,
                    2=verbose output, 3=very verbose output
      -settings=SETTINGS   The Python path to a settings module, e.g.
                     "myproject.settings.main". If this isn't provided, the
                      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable will be
                      used.
       --pythonpath=PYTHONPATH
                      A directory to add to the Python path, e.g.
                      "/home/djangoprojects/myproject".
      --traceback           Print traceback on exception
       --version             show program's version number and exit
       -h, --help            show this help message and exit
     Traceback (most recent call last)
          File "C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
         management.execute_from_command_line()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
         453, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
376, in execute
    sys.stdout.write(self.main_help_text() + '\n')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
242, in main_help_text
    for name, app in six.iteritems(get_commands()):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
109, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 53, in __ge
tattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 48, in _set
up
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 134, in __i
nit__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s"
% (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): N
o module named settings

c:\Python27\Scripts>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did was to add an environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings` and after ater that, either uninstall the module OR yesterday you used to only run the `django-admin.py` command from inside the specific directory where `mysite` was located.

To solve this:

**Solution 1**:Remove the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable (i'd suggest this)

**Solution 2**: run `django-admin.py` command from inside the directory you were running it yesterday

**Sollution 3**:Explicitly run `django-admin.py whatever --settings=some.good.settings.module`

But really, just do 1 anyway. it's saner that way.

If you don't know how to remove environment variables, check out google, it's pretty simple, and you should remember it anyway, cuz you did it yesterday :P (or check out this [link](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html)

Comment: unset DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE Removes DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE